# how to link button with a layout to display on click?

Tags: android, button, layout, onclick

I am new to android and I have this doubt and looking for best way to do it. I just want to click a button to display a layout. currently I did this by creating a second activity. problem is when I use lot of buttons do i have to create more activity for that or any other way I can just use a layout to be displayed onclick  of button.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

They enable you to have multiple layouts for a single activity (and much more). Take some time to explore them, they are a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`View.setVisibility(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) to hide/display parts of your layout on the click of a button.

Example:

```
mLayout.findViewById(R.id.group1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
mLayout.findViewById(R.id.group2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```